# How to make a complete Iframe registration / login / userpanel

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, user-accounts, login-script

So far i have such code

```
<form action="register.php" target="login" type=post>
  <label for="name">Account </label><br><br>
   <input type=text id="name" name="account" size=20 maxlength=<?php Echo MaxNameLength; ?> /><br><br>
  <label for="name">Password</label><br><br>
   <input type=text id="name" name="password" size=20 maxlength=<?php Echo MaxNameLength; ?> /><br><br>
  <button type=submit>Register</button>
</form>
```

I placed it inside an IFrame but when i try to use php with such code:

```
<?php
  If (IsSet($_GET["account"]["password"])) { $Account = $_GET["account"]; $Password = $_GET["password"]; 

$AllRight = True;

    For ($I=0; $I<StrLen(WrongChars); $I++) {
      If (StrPos($Account, SubStr(WrongChars,$I,1))) {
        Echo "<p>Your Name musn't contain the char \"".SubStr(WrongChars,$I,1)."\"</p>";
        $AllRight = False;
      }
    }
    If (file_exists(AccountFilesPath.$Account.AccountFilesEnding)) {
      Echo "<p>This Account already exists!</p>";
      $AllRight = False;
    }
    If ($AllRight) {
      $Text .= "$Password ";

      File_Put_Contents (AccountFilesPath.$Account.AccountFilesEnding, $Text);

      if(!file_exists(AccountFilesPath.$Account.AccountFilesEnding)) {
        echo "<p>Error during account cration!</p>";
      }

      Echo "<p>This Account is created succesfully!</p>";
    }
  }
?>
```

yet the responce im getting is a fresh registration page with no work done... 
i want my iframe to individually register text files like (user1.txt) with ($Password) inside. Along with having a link to the login, and upon login have a User Control Panel.

Comment: what the hell is that language? Functions in php don't start with uppercase

Comment: @PhiterFernandes php functions are case insensitive, and most likely `WrongChars` and `AccountFilesPath` defined constant, its just not added in this code the OP posted.

Comment: hahaha that's really weird XD

Comment: Didn't know, thanks for sharing!

Comment: I think stackoverflow uppercased some of the code, but yes those are already defined, i just didnt feel the need to post it

Comment: `$_GET["account"]["password"]` will never be set, nor would `$_POST["account"]["password"]`. Those are 2 different indexes of `$_POST/GET`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using an iframe for this but I can see that you use $_GET in your php when your form submits $_POST (type="post")

Try changing that in your PHP code and see if it works

Edit*
As stated in the comments this is not a $_GET index $_GET["account"]["password"]

Let's say you stick with POST since your html form submits a POST,you must use something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["account"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
```

And to be sure what variables you get from your form, I recommend you to print your Post array before any manipulation.

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: GET finds the variable where as POST works just as well... and ive tried both